# Moving all imports to a separate file

Tags: python, import, module, package

My Python project is starting to get out of hand, with about 20 lines of imports at the start. Is it acceptable practice to move all of these to a new file `import_config.py` and `from import_config import *` back in my main file?

Comment: No: that completely breaks the point of explicit imports, because now you're back to not easily being able to see what's currently in scope. Why not break up *the code*, rather than the imports?

Comment: Removal of 20 (and addition of one, thus 19) lines of code will save your project?

Comment: you should restructure your project so that one file does one thing, then call or use those things from a master file. encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, that helped my brain click over to what the real issue is, breaking the code up into smaller chunks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you update the variable `__all__` in your `__init__.py`, can be possible define theses imports only one time for your's submodules.

```
__all__ = ['script1', 'script2', 'script3']
```

See details into python [modules documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).